Julia seg faults when attempting to use pkg
I was having some issues with my julia install so I tried a clean install, and now I'm having issues using it at all. Attempting to add any package, or running "] status", results in a seg fault.
(@v1.10) pkg> add Revise
  Installing known registries into `~/.julia`
┌ Warning: attempting to remove probably stale pidfile
│   path = "/home/<user>/.julia/registries/.pid"
└ @ FileWatching.Pidfile ~/.julia/juliaup/julia-1.10.5+0.x64.linux.gnu/share/julia/stdlib/v1.10/FileWatching/src/pidfile.jl:273
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


Are you using Manjaro? This is perfectly in line with a known issue with the Manjaro Package manager, read about a similar issue here https://discourse.julialang.org/t/segmentation-fault-when-installing-packages/39067/3 . If so, install using the official binaries. Even if not, a reinstall from binaries seems like a reasonable future step.

delete .julia folder and sub folders. Then call Julia again.
